# How to import keras-vggface in google colab?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I tried to import `keras-vggface` like this:

```
from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
```

But it always gives me this error

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_vggface".

I tried to install `keras_vggface` with pip like this:

```
!pip install --user keras-vggface

!pip install keras-vggface 

!pip install git+https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface.git
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to install it as below:

```
!pip install keras_vggface
```

this works like a charm.
Hope it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with VGGFace use in colab as well, resolved your problem by specifying in colab tensor flow x1 with `%tensorflow_version 1.x`as informed by colab warning [VGGFace git](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface):

```
"VGGFAce works only with 1.x TensorFlow backend AND without eager execution!!!"
```

EDIT: but you have to properly call `!pip install keras_vggface` first